# Limit of Sequence of unusual Prime Product

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, sequences-and-series, prime-number-theorem

Let $p_n$ be the nth prime and $p_L$ be closest to its square root:
\begin{equation}
  p_L^2 \approx p_n \approx x
\end{equation}

Let $\sigma \in Z^+$ be a positive integer constant.  Define the average slope as
\begin{equation}
  M_{n} = \prod_{\sigma < p_i \leq p_n} 
   \left( \frac{p_i - \sigma}{p_i} \right)
\end{equation}

Asymptotically the average slope becomes
\begin{equation}
  M_{n} \sim \frac{K(\sigma)}{e^{\sigma \gamma} (\ln p_n)^\sigma}
  \quad n \rightarrow \infty
\end{equation}
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni Constant and
\begin{equation} 
  K(\sigma) = \sum_{p_i \leq \sigma} \frac{\sigma}{p_i}
\end{equation}

Now define the square weighted slope as
\begin{equation}
  S_{n} = \sum_{p_L < p_i \leq p_n} 
  \frac{p_i^2 - p_{i-1}^2}{p_n^2 - p_L^2} M_{i-1}
  = \frac{(p_{L+1}^2 - p_{L}^2) M_{L} +
  \ldots + (p_{n}^2 - p_{n-1}^2) M_{n-1}}{p_n^2 - p_L^2} 
\end{equation}

Asympototically,
\begin{equation}
  S_{n} \sim \frac{C(\sigma)}{(\ln p_n)^\sigma}
  \quad n \rightarrow \infty
\end{equation}
My question is: what is $C(\sigma)$?  Is $C(\sigma) = K(\sigma)$?  If $C(1) = K(1) = 1$, then I have an exciting new proof of the Prime Number Theorem.

More information can be found at:
  http://www.ugcs.caltech.edu/~kel/MPP/GammaSquares.pdf
Thank you.